# Facebook Fluid Canvas with AngularJS

Tags: facebook, angularjs

I have a Facebook game that use AngularJS.
After the game load the data the height of the game page is growing.
The problem is now there are 2 scrollbars.

How can I make Facebook resize my page to match the new heigh?

Comment: Try to put FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();  when FB is loaded/ready

Comment: I'm already calling it. The problem is that Angular load the data and present it after FB is ready. I'll try to catch that event and call this method.

Comment: Try to use promise with the data loaded like promise.then(function(data){FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); })